# Invalid number error while executing query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your help in an error which I'm getting, I'm using the below query in order to see the average of a percentage column in my table, but it is giving me the below error message:

> ```
> ORA-01722: invalid number
> 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> ```

Query:

```
SELECT 'Skybox' as Platform,avg(PER_OF_VIOLATING_RULES) as 
ComplianceCalculation from table_name
```

Values in the `PER_OF_VIOLATING_RULES` column:

```
PER_OF_VIOLATING_RULES
32.08%
55.77%
54.19%
54.84%
16.13%
23.22%
29.50%
5.56%
48.50%
56.04%
```

`PER_OF_VIOLATING_RULES` column is a `varchar2` Datatype.

Comment: SQL Server <> Oracle

Comment: The string `'32.08%'` is not a valid number

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `%` sign:

```
 SELECT 'Skybox' as Platform,avg(replace(PER_OF_VIOLATING_RULES, '%', '')) as ComplianceCalculation from table_name
```

Comment: Just few sec ahead. Exactly same answer. I delete mine,

Comment: I would think you would want to explicitly cast PER_OF_VIOLATING_RULES as a number (e.g `to_number`).